# Timer in Starling Framework

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, starling-framework

Hello everybody I am developing a game with starling and i want to set a timer for example every 2 sec i want something to happen.
I used the juggler elapsed prop but i wonder is there a more effecient way to do that

thank you,

Khaled

Comment: thank you for marking negative and not understanding my question
ps : i don't want to use Timer because i already have ENTER_FRAME event and this is too much for the device to handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this does not relate to animation, it is recommended to use a Timer for non-animated content.

Timer implementation would be higher performance than additional time calculations on enter frame handler.

If you are advancing Starling Jugglers, you can set the frame rate of the Juggler to every 2-seconds.

Jugglers also have `delayCall` in which you could infinitely loop every 2-seconds if your functor redundantly called delayCall:

```
juggler.delayCall(functor, 2.0);
```

To tie in to Starlings frame / render lifecycle, you can test time since your last call.

```
private var lastCallTime:int

protected function frameHandler():void
{
    var now:int = getTimer();
    var ellapsed:int = now - lastCallTime;
    if(ellapsed >= 2000)
    {
        /* execute implementation */
        lastCallTime = now;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an extension that implements Timer functionality using the Starling.juggler for compatibility:
http://wiki.starling-framework.org/extensions/starling_timer

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, you can use the "DelayedCall" class. It's easy to miss! ;-)

```
var delayedCall:DelayedCall = new DelayedCall(method, 2.0);
delayedCall.repeatCount = int.MAX_VALUE;
Starling.juggler.add(delayedCall);

function method():void
{
    trace("ping");
}
```

Comment: Just as a follow up to this, this helped me out as well. But instead of doing an int.MAX_VALUE, the API now supports setting the repeatCount to 0 to make the repeat indefinite.

Comment: I added an extension that implements Timer functionality using the Starling.juggler for compatibility:
http://wiki.starling-framework.org/extensions/starling_timer